# Pegar o texto entre uma tag

Tags: php, html

Tenho essa string `<td id="aui_3_2_0_1196">500</td>`, gostaria de pegar o valor `500` entre a *tag* de início e fim (`<td id="aui_3_2_0_1196">` e `</td>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente:

```
$text = '<td id="aui_3_2_0_1196">500</td>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Qualquer coisa vai comentando.

Comment: Valeu! Ajudou pra caramba!