# Como pegar o texto de uma span?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Por exemplo, nessa linha de código eu preciso do "x+10=10".
Alguém sabe como fazer?

```
<span class="task" onclick="loadExercise(201)" id="task201">x+10=10</span>
```

Comment: Não sei exatamente qual o intuito de usar selenium, mas veja se está resposta lhe serve: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163557/pegar-o-texto-entre-uma-tag/163561#163561

Comment: Acho que vai depender da linguagem que vc quer usar: Java, Python, C#...

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando python por exemplo pode usar o .text:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_id("task201").text
print (name)

x+10=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que assim dá:

```
var elemento = browser.FindElement(By.Id("task201")).Text;
```

ou

```
var elemento = browser.FindElement(By.Id("task201")).GetAttribute("innerText");
```

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro precisa identificar se o elemento é dinâmico ou seja ele faz parte de uma lista e cada vez que ele aparecer poderá ser em um local diferente, o meio mais comum e seguro para capturar texto é assim:

```
texto String;

texto = driver.findElemnt(By.xpath(//span [text()='x+10=10'])).text; //desta forma ele vai localizar o texto mesmo que ele mude de posição na pagina
```