# Como pegar xpath de elemento no span

Tags: python, xpath

Eu estou utilizando `lxml`junto com `Python 3.8`e estou precisando pegar o xpath de um texto que está dentro dessa parte do html:

```
<span class="text-down">7424.65</span>
```

O xpath é:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p[2]/span
```

Eu estou tentando utilizar:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p[2]/span/text()
```

Mas me retorna apenas: []

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Meu código é esse:

```
Pagina = requests.get('https://www.bitrue.com/trade/btc_usdt')
Pagina = html.fromstring(Bitrue_pagina.content)
Pagina_Valor = Bitrue_pagina.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p[1]/text()')

print(Pagina_Valor)
```

Ele geralmente funciona em outros elementos, só que não sei se é porque é este elemento é constantemente atualizado (ele não é um valor fixo) mas nunca está conseguindo pegar ele..

Eu encontrei isto [Como pegar o texto de uma span?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168839/como-pegar-o-texto-de-uma-span) mas é utilizando o selenium, e a intenção é otimizar o código, não quero gastar tempo abrindo o navegador

Se alguém souber me informar ficarei muito grato :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro passo no scraping é procurar uma API oficial. No caso desse site, [tem um link no final da página](https://github.com/Bitrue-exchange/Market-API) informando as rotas de requisições.

---

**Se não tivesse:**

Você não consegue pegar o texto porque ele não está no HTML; ele é carregado, pelo que vejo, inicialmente por JavaScript e depois atualizado por Websockets.

Se você apertar F12 pra abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador e recarregar o site, vai ver as requisições que ele faz. Uma delas é pra URL `https://www.bitrue.com/exchange-web/web/coin/coinRateList`, que retorna um JSON:

```
{"code":"200","msg":"suc","params_num":null,"params":null,"data":{"BTC":{"BTC":"1","USDT":"7513.53","time":"1572000295393"},"XRP":{"BTC":"0.00003746","USDT":"0.28","time":"1572000295412"},"ETH":{"BTC":"0.02182030","USDT":"164.01","time":"1572000295432"},"USDT":{"BTC":"0.00013307","USDT":"1","time":"1572000295400"}}}
```

Logo, o código relevante é:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.bitrue.com/exchange-web/web/coin/coinRateList')
dados = r.json()

print(dados['data']['BTC']['USDT'])  # 7535.36
```

Se for atualizar com muita frequência, vale a pena fazer uma engenharia reversa pra usar a conexão websockets, que poupa a sua banda e a deles.

Comment: Excelente, muitissimo obrigado pela respsosta

Comment: Uma dúvida: Onde você viu o link que ele faz a requisição ? Eu procurei aqui e não consegui encontrar

Comment: @user3602803 tem que abrir a aba de ferramentas de desenvolvedor antes de carregar a página, porque as requisições não são gravadas antes que a aba esteja aberta, e essa é feita imediatamente após a página ser carregada.

Comment: Mas em que pagina do F12? Pq não vejo ela em "Elements" e nem em "Console" =\

Comment: Na aba "Network".