# Como pegar parte do texto de um formulário para enviar para uma tabela

Tags: php, post

Tenho um formulário que após ser processado gera um arquivo de excel com os dados desse formulário usando $_POST para pegar os valores.

Eu preciso de uma forma de pegar o nome que aparece do lado de cada input para enviar no excel também. abaixo como estão os inputs

```
<div>
 <input type="number" value="5" name="form[p1]" id="p1" > Produto A
</div>
<div>
 <input type="number" value="0" name="form[p2]" id="p2" > Produto B
</div>
```

Os ids dos inputs vão de p1 até p77. Tenho uma função em php que me traz apenas os inputs com valores diferentes de "0".

Tem alguma forma de fazer ele pegar o Nome do produto (Produto A, por exemplo)?

Para eu poder gerar no excel (table convertida em excel) assim:

```
<td>5</td><td>Produto A</td>
```

Eu fiz usando uma consulta MYSQL pegando o id do input e tranzendo o nome e ele traz o nome certinho, o problema é que ao terminar de enviar o email, dá um erro na página: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Quando faço sem a consulta MYSQL ele não dá erro

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163557/pegar-o-texto-entre-uma-tag/163561#163561

Comment: Não tem como. Vc deve enviar o nome do produto no $_POST para capturá-lo no script. Se é que entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Existem recursos para fazer isto, mas aí vc vai ter que mexer em uns jQuery no seu código. A ideia era enviar no _value_ de cada input algo assim: `value="5_Produto A"`. Quando vc der o submit, o PHP irá separar o número do nome do produto e fazer a aplicação.