# Como copiar um pedaço de texto dentro de uma textarea

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma texto escrito numa `<TextArea>` em uma página *html* e gostava de em *php* ler o texto e retirar um pedaço dele e escrever em uma outra `<TextArea>`, tentei usar o `preg_match` mas não consegui intender bem o funcionamento dele, vamos a dados.

**Texto:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello World </h1>  
    <h2> está </h2>
    <h1> TUDO? </h1>     
</body>
</html>
```

**Resposta:**

> Hello World
>   TUDO?

Preciso ler o que estiver entre `<h1>` e `</h1>`.

**Código:**

```
<textarea name="resultcode" cols="130" rows="30" wrap="OFF">
<?php
    $html = $_POST['htmlcode'];
    echo preg_match_all('/<h1>(.*)</h1>(.*)/i',$html, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
</textarea>
```

**ERRO:**

> ```
> <br />
> <b>Warning</b>:  preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'h' in <b>/home/u982560592/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
> NULL
> ```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163557/pegar-o-texto-entre-uma-tag/163561#163561

Comment: @MagicHat já testei a resposta foi em branco

Comment: Como vc testou?

Comment: @MagicHat não funciona porque se tiver mais tags vai mostrar todas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O preg_match e o preg_match_all utilizam REGEX e retornam um boolean indicando se a expressão (padrão) foi encontrado. Sobre Expressões regulares vc pode tirar suas dúvidas [aqui](http://aurelio.net/regex/) e testar [aqui](http://regexr.com/)

Quanto ao problema em si, você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
// Pega o POST
$html = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'htmlcode');

// Se encontrar algum <h1> no html...
if(preg_match('/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/iU', $html, $match)){
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Para pegar mais de uma ocorrência, use o `preg_match_all`, assim:

```
<?php
// Pega o POST
$html = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'htmlcode');

// Se encontrar algum <h1> no html...
if(preg_match_all('/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/iU', $html, $match)){
    // Pega as ocorrencias do conteúdo de <h1>
    $ocorrencias = $match[1];
    // Tem alguma ocorrência?
    if(!empty($ocorrencias)){
        // Lê uma a uma
        foreach($ocorrencias as $index => $ocorrencia){
            // Exibe cada uma das ocorrências do conteúdo de <h1>
            echo "$index - $ocorrencia <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Explicando os modificadores**

Note que no REGEX dentro de `preg_match()` tudo que está dentro de `/` é o padrão. o que está fora são modificadores. O modificador `i` indica para ignorar 
o case (maiusculas e minusculas) e o modificador `U` indica para o REGEX não ser guloso, isto é, em ".*" ele irá parar de pegar quando achar o proximo padrão que é `</h1>`. Note tb que em `<\/h1>` foi escapado a barra para o REGEX não confundir com a barra de fechamento.

Você pode ver mais sobre os modificadores [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: O código assim funciona, mas vamos supor que em vez de 1 <h1> tenho 2.. já tentei remover '(.*)' e '.*' mas não resultou.

Comment: @Tmc modifiquei a resposta para atender sua dúvida

Comment: @Tmc além da resposta mais completa, sobre o q vc disse que removeu os parenteses: não faça isso. Os parênteses indicam grupo. É o conteúdo deles que será salvo dentro de $match. Se não tiver os parênteses, nada é pego.

Answer (score -1):

Não faça *parse* de HTML usando `preg_match`.

Use a [Classe DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Exemplo:

```
<?php 

$html= "<p>Olá!</p>
<h1>Titulo H1</h1>
<h2>Titulo H2</h2>
<h3>Titulo H3</h3>";
// Cria um novo objeto DOM
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
// Carrega o HTML no Objeto
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
//remove espaços em branco
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$hTwo= $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); // Defina aqui a sua tag desejada
echo $hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue; 
//Irá retornar "Titulo H2";
?>
```

Se perceber estou imprimindo `$hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue` onde `item(0)` possui o índice do item que eu pegarei o `nodeValue`.

Caso haja mais de um item `<h2>` na página `$hTwo->length` irá retornar o total de itens com o mesmo *TagName* na página, então você pode fazer um laço para imprimir todos estes elementos

Exemplo:

```
<?php 
$html = "<p>Olá!</p>
    <h1>Titulo H1</h1>
    <h2>Titulo H2</h2>
    <h2>Titulo H2 2</h2>";
// Cria um novo objeto DOM
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
// Carrega o HTML no Objeto
$dom->loadHTML($html);
//remove espaços em branco
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$hTwo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); // Defina aqui a sua tag desejada
for ($i = 0; $i < $hTwo->length; $i++) {
    echo $hTwo->item($i)->nodeValue."<br>";
}
//Irá retornar "Titulo H2<br>Titulo H2 2;
?>
```

Comment: o código assim só funciona mas vamos supor que em vez de 1 <h2> tenho 2 no código a forma de mostrar os dois? esqueci de adicionar isso a pergunta

Comment: Editado com a resposta para sua pergunta

Comment: Mesmo que hava apenas um este código irá funcionar.

Comment: Está a funcionar seu exemplo, +/- porque eu preciso de pegar o texto da TextArea, mas quando eu uso o código $html = $_POST['htmlcode']; para pegar o texto dá-me erro. 

PS: Se fizer como está no exemplo está a funcionar

Comment: @Tmc Isso se dá pq provavelmente o que está vindo do textarea não tem um código HTML válido. Para o seu caso, no entando, acredito que a utilização de preg_match_all será suficiente, como indicado aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233752/como-copiar-um-peda%C3%A7o-de-texto-dentro-de-uma-textarea/233766#233766